# geometrically speaking, what is the topological difference between $\mathcal{R^2}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ space?

Tags: general-topology

Is there any geometric difference between the two?  $\mathcal{R}^3$ and $\mathcal{R}^2$ are spaces that don't have bijective mapping. But the complex space can be bijectively mapped to a $\mathcal{R}^2$ space. Right?

Comment: From the topological viewpoint, they are equal. Similarly, they have the same (real) smooth structure. The only difference is that $\mathbb{C}$ has an additional, complex, structure.

Comment: BTW, there *is* a bijection between $\Bbb R^3$ and $\Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Topologically speaking, there is no difference. Indeed, as long as there's a homeomorphism between two spaces, they're identical as far as Topology is concerned.

Their "true" difference is that $\mathbb{C}$ possesses a multiplication under which it is a group (provided we remove $0$), while $\mathbb{R}^2$ doesn't even have a multiplication between two of its elements.

By the way, it is not true that there is no bijection between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$. [Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.carolynrabbott.com/uploads/3/0/8/1/30819067/113_r2r1_bijection.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiu4Maxx_frAhXMMewKHc5GBLwQFjABegQIDxAG&usg=AOvVaw25X4IckuX9rwGAk8epIWoP) for more details.

Comment: The plane has the multiplication of the direct product, but this doesn’t even get close to the group property you mention for the complex numbers.